# Non-Functioning Mac App Store

Tags: macos, mac

When attempting to upgrade my OS on my MacBook Pro to Yosemite (currently 10.9.5) by launching the App Store, I receive the following empty screen.  I had previously begun successfully downloading Yosemite through the App Store several days earlier, but decided to pause the download.  After that point the App Store has become unusable.

Any thoughts on a possible resolution?

[image]

Comment: What does the "All Messages" log stream in Console.app say when you launch the App Store.app?